# Using JFrame.add function in different classes

Tags: java, swing

I'm having a trouble with this task. I have 2 classes:

```
public class MainJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public Labels labels;

public MainJFrame() {


    setSize(1024, 960);
    setTitle("er");
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    labels = new Labels();
    labels.addLabels();

}

public static MainJFrame application;
public static void main(String[] args) {
        application = new MainJFrame();
        application.setVisible(true);
}


}
```

and second class:

```
public class Labels {


public JLabel l_acceleration; 


public void addLabels() {   
   MainJFrame.application.add(MainJFrame.application.labels.l_acceleration);    
}


public Labels() {

    l_acceleration = new JLabel("acc");
        l_acceleration.setBounds(90, 90, 90, 20);

}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui.Labels.addLabels(Labels.java:12)
    at cardmaker.MainJFrame.<init>(MainJFrame.java:16)
    at cardmaker.MainJFrame.main(MainJFrame.java:22)
```

What can be the problem there? I can't find solution anywhere around the web. The problem I think is somewhere near:
    MainJFrame.application.add(MainJFrame.application.labels.l_acceleration); 
Why I can't use this function in my constructor?
Is there a way I can do this? I really need it.

Comment: I'm sure this will get closed as a duplicate in a moment, but at the point in code where you get the error, you haven't finished executing the constructor yet, and the assignment to `application` in `main()` hasn't happened yet.  You're still executing the `new MainJFrame()` part of that code.

Comment: @markspace it's just a part of my code, and what u meant by executing new MainJframe()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainJFrame` class, you declare a field named `application`.

```
public static MainJFrame application;
```

Since this is a static field, by the time your application reaches your main method this field has automatically been initialized with the default value of `null`. Then in your main class you give this instruction:

```
application = new MainJFrame();
```

before `application` is assigned to the new value, MainJFrame's constructor must run to its completion. The constructor starts and eventually creates a new `Labels` object and calls `addLabels` in it.

The problem is, the `addLabels` method calls `MainJFrame.application.add`. Note that it's referring to `MainJFrame.application`, but since the constructor hasn't yet completed the value of `MainJFrame.application` hasn't yet been changed from the default value of `null`, so you get a NullPointerException.

One way you can fix this is to pass the reference to MainJFrame directly into Labels and referencing it that way:

```
public void addLabels(MainJFrame f) {   
   f.add(f.labels.l_acceleration);    
}
```

...and in the constructor call `addLabels` like this:

```
labels.addLabels(this); // `this` contains a reference to the MainJFrame object currently under construction
```

Note that this still isn't great code, but that's a more advanced topic for another day.  :)

Comment: So what should I do? I think that it should be static because I need this in another class.

Comment: @PiotrKostański I edited the answer to show the changes you need to make.

Comment: I just tried this and it's working. Thank you and thanks for 'this' description.

Comment: @PiotrKostański I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    application = new MainJFrame();
    Labels j = new Labels();
    j.addLabels();
    application.setVisible(true);
```

}

You can use this code to solve your problem.

instead of calling addLabels() in MainJFrame() call it into the main().